# SQL unique PK for grouped data in SP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, solr

I am trying to build a temp table with grouped data from multiple tables (in an SP), I am successful in building the data set however I have a requirement that each grouped row have a unique id. I know there are ways to generate unique ids for each row, However the problem I have is that I need the id for a given row to be the same on each run regardless of the number of rows returned.

Example:

**1st run:**

`ID   Column A    Column B
  1      apple      15
  2      orange     10
  3      grape      11`

**2nd run:**

`ID   Column A    Column B
   3      grape      11`

The reason I want this is because i am sending this data up to **SOLR** and when I do a delta I need to have the ID back for the same row as its trying to re-index

Any way I can do this?

Comment: please show the query that gets you that data. or a simplified version of it. ideally, each row should have a fixed id somewhere that you use as an external reference in other places for doing a delta.

Comment: `SELECT row_number() over(order by Id) 'Id', type, Count(*) 'Count' FROM  #MasterBucket WITH(NOLOCK)
 GROUP BY Type`

#MasterBucket contains the data set i mentioned in my inital post

Comment: So is the problem that the ID you are ordering by, is not unique, so you cannot determine the order in which it is organised, to create the row number, that you are using as an ID? And currently in your second run, using your sample data, the ID for grape would show 1, but you want it to maintain 3, as that is what it was given in the first run?

Comment: @Leonidas199x - that is correct

Comment: @TheConfusedCoder and what is the time difference between runs? Presumably this could be any time at all, and you would want the ID it has been assigned to be persistent?

Comment: Yes, it could be any time since the SOLR delta is called when a user makes a change on the page and when the delta is called it will check for the changed record and hence the ID needs to be persistent

Comment: @TheConfusedCoder Understood. The only way I can think to do this is to create a 'staging' table, where you insert the data you have assigned an ID to, with its new assigned ID, its ID from its source table, and the name, or an ID, that relates to the source table. That way you can always check against that table to see if you have already assigned that row an ID, you can also create new IDs based on the last ID in that table. Not very pretty is all.

Comment: Well like i said in my initial post i am building the data from multiple tables and dumping them into a temp table to group them and send it out to solr, so when the data updates in those tables i need to re-run my SP and then build on the data set again, so staging it wouldn't be possible T_T

i know this is really a mind blower.

Comment: @TheConfusedCoder Without some sample data, I am finding it hard to understand exactly why you couldn't stage it. If you can, can you add some to the question?

Comment: @Leonidas199x sure i will add them once i get back home, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, i was stuck with something else, however i solved my own issue.

I built 2 temp tables one with all the data from the various tables (#master) and another temp table (#final) to house all the grouped data with an empty column for ID

Next i did a concat(column1, '-',column2,'-', column3) on 3 columns from the #master and updated the #final table based on the type

this helped me to get the same concat ids on each run

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, not entirely confident of your wider picture, but ... 
As your new data is assembled, log each [column a] value in a table of your own.
Give that table an IDENTITY column to do the numbering for you.

Now you can join any new data sets to your lookup table and you'll have a persistent number for each column A.

You just need to ensure that each time you query new data, you add new values to the lookup table.

```
create table dbo.myRef(
    idx int identity(1,1)
    ,[A] nvarchar(100)
 )
```

General draft as below ...

```
--- just simulating some input data here
with cte as (
 select 'apple' as [A], 15 as [B]
 UNION
 select 'orange' as [A], 10 as [B]
 UNION
 select 'banana' as [A], 4 as [B]
) 
select * into #temp from cte;

-- Put any new values into the lookup table
-- and they will be assigned a new index number by the identity column
insert into dbo.myRef([A])
select distinct [A] 
from #temp where [A] not in (select [A] from dbo.myRef)

-- now pull your original data for output, joining to the lookup table to get a ref number.
 select T.*,R.idx
 from   #temp T
    inner join 
    oer.myRef R
    on T.[A] = R.[A]
```